# How to rectify this error class is not key value coding in ios?

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I need to iterate the "c"id,"project" id,name in the following JSON response:

```
    {
      "a": {
        "user": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "b"
        },
        "startday": "2015-12-27",
        "status": "New",
        "total": 6,
        "c": [
          {
          "id": 768,
          "project": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "d"
          },
          "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "b"
          },
          "activity": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "e"
          },
          "hours": 2,
          "comments": "",
          "spent_on": "2015-12-27"
        },
        {
          "id": 775,
          "project": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "d"
        },
        "user": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "b"
        },
        "activity": {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "e"
        },
        "hours": 4,
        "comments": "",
        "spent_on": "2015-12-28"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

I've tried

```
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainerserror:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonObjects);
if ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"] != [NSNull null]) {
  NSArray *itemArray = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"];
  for (NSDictionary *itemDic in itemArray){
    NSString * user;
    NSArray *user_data =[itemDic valueForKey:@"c"];
    user = [user_data valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"%@",user);
  }
}
```

which throws the error

```
This class is not key value coding complaint for the key c.
```

Then I tried

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =[NSJSONSerializationJSONObjectWithData:jsonSource  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray * time_entrid = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"a.c.id"];
NSLog(@"%@",time_entrid);
```

How can I solve the error I've mentioned above and iterate properly? Does using the second way enable me to iterate too?

Comment: ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"c"] returns an array not ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"]. You are getting a dictionary from ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"] not an array.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS how to correct it bro...can you change the piece of code. please

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also, please edit your expectations alongside that process. **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have One NSArray and NSDictionary 
For "a" NSDictionary use (you can't iterate NSDictionary only way is)

```
[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"]
```

you will get 1, change id by name you will get b

For NSArray

```
[[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"c"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]
```

you will get id 768

For project id

```
[[[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"c"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"project"] objectForKey:@"id"]
```

you will get 8

```
[[[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"c"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"project"] objectForKey:@"name"]
```

you will get name

to iterate array use

```
for(int i=0; i<[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"c"] count];i++)
{

NSLog(@"%@", [[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"c"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

Comment: i tried like this sir : NSArray * itemarray = [jsonobjects objectforkey:@"c"];        then  for(nsdictionary * dict in itemarray) {   NSString * value = [dict valueforkey:@"id"];  }  but it shows null ..what's the error sir.

Comment: Try NSArray * itemarray = [[[jsonobjects objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"c"];

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *array_c = [json objectForKey: @"c"];

for(NSDictionary *dictn_c in array_c)

{

NSString *id_str = [dictn_c objectForKey:@"id"];

NSDictionary *project_dictn = [dictn_c objectForKey: @"project"];

NSString *project_id_str = [project_dictn objectForKey:@"id"];

}
This should work

Comment: Please check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *array_c = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"c"];

NSArray *id_arr = [array_c valueForKey:@"id"];

This will give you array of "id"

Comment: Please refrain from adding a second anwer; instead edit your previous answer to include the new information.

Comment: @Reshmi Majumder  NSDictionary *dictn_a = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"a"]; then in for loop what i have to do...that;s confusing me please help me

Comment: NSDictionary *dictn_a = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"c"]; not "a" and NSArray *id_arr = [dictn_a valueForKey:@"id"]; this will give you an array as [8,775] , i.e. an array of id.

Comment: k then in for loop for (NSDictionary *itemdic in dictn_a) or for(nsarray * dict in dictn_a) this is what i am asking...

Comment: NSArray array_c = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"c"];
for(NSDictionary *dictn in array_c)
{
}

Comment: i wnat to iterate the values ....using for loop. so how to do this ? take a look at code. please ..

Comment: For Project id NSArray *arr_project = [array_c valueForKey: @"project"]; //this will give you array of projects in array_c.
Then you can use for loop same as above

Comment: NSArray array_c = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"c"]; for(NSDictionary *dictn in array_c) { NSArray * data1 = [dictn valueforkey:@"id"]; }  it shows null what is the error in this...